# Built-in extensions for Autodesk Viewer

Tags: webgl, autodesk-viewer

The [Autodesk Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/api/viewerapi/) can load some extensions on the 'new Autodesk.Vieweing.Viewer3D' constructor, but what are the available options? The code below came [from this tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/api/view-and-data-api/#step-7-load-the-urn-in-the-javascript-viewer).

```
function initialize() {
   var options = {
      'document' : 'urn:<<SOME URN HERE>>',
      'env':'AutodeskProduction',
      'getAccessToken': getToken,
      'refreshToken': getToken,
   };
   var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
   var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(viewerElement, { /* Extensions here? */});
   Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(
      options,
      function() {
         viewer.initialize();
         loadDocument(viewer, options.document);
      }
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to this question about loading viewer extensions is to provide an object like this one:

```
{
    extensions: [
        'Autodesk.IoTTool', 'Autodesk.FirstPerson'
    ]
}
```

and the viewer will call Viewer3D.loadExtension (name, this.config) for you during initialization. The name can be either Autodesk extensions, or your own extensions like shown on this [example](https://github.com/cyrillef/Pier9.IoT). See the IoTTool extension which is local vs the FirstPerson extension which is coming from the Autodesk server.

However, this config object can do a lot more. For example:

```
{
    startOnInitialize: boolean, // (default true) the default behavior is to run the main loop immediately, unless startOnInitialize is provided and is to false.

    canvasConfig: { // (default Viewer3D.kDefaultCanvasConfig)
        disableSpinner: boolean,
        disableMouseWheel: boolean, // (default false) the name tells it
        disableTwoFingerSwipe: boolean, // (default false)

        COMMAND: {
            onObject: ACTIONS,
            offObject: ACTIONS
        },

        ...

        // COMMAND: click, clickAlt, clickCtrl, clickShift, clickCtrlShift
        // ACTIONS: selectOnly, selectToggle, deselectAll, isolate, showAll, setCOI, focus, hide

    },

    extensions: [], // will call this.loadExtension(extensions[i], this.config)

    onTriggerContextMenuCallback: <function callback>, // function (event) {}
    onTriggerSelectionChangedCallback: <function callback>, // function (event) {dbid}
    onTriggerDoubleTapCallback: <function callback>, // function (event) {}
    onTriggerSingleTapCallback: <function callback>, // function (event) {}

    viewableName: string, // the name appearing on the model dialog box

    screenModeDelegate: <class>, // to control fullscreen behaviour
}
```

The Viewer3D.kDefaultCanvasConfig defaults are:

```
Viewer3D.kDefaultCanvasConfig = {
    "click": {
        "onObject": ["selectOnly"],
        "offObject": ["deselectAll"]
    },
    "clickAlt": {
        "onObject": ["setCOI"],
        "offObject": ["setCOI"]
    },
    "clickCtrl": {
        "onObject": ["selectToggle"],
        "offObject": ["deselectAll"]
    },
    "clickShift": {
        "onObject": ["selectToggle"],
        "offObject": ["deselectAll"]
    },

    // Features that support disabling
    "disableSpinner": false,
    "disableMouseWheel": false,
    "disableTwoFingerSwipe": false
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer to load extensions explicitly one by one, which allows to pass specific options for each one (if needed): viewer.loadExtension('MyCustomExtension', {enableAutoBugFix: true, enableKickAssFeatures: true}) ...